# nginx: regex not matching URI

Tags: nginx, regex

i have this URI `/orls/myservice/f?p=4550` and the following location

```
location ~ "^/(.+)/myservice/f?p=(.+)$" {
 .....
}
```

nginx is returning a 404 not found. the problem might come from the ? so i tried `\?` buit i'm still getting the same error. Can anyone help ?

Comment: what exactly you need to match from here: /orls/myservice/f?p=4550

Answer (score 2):

The location match does not consider the query string:

```
Note that locations of all types test only a URI part of request line 
without arguments. This is done because arguments in the query string 
may be given in several ways [...]
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try also to escape the **/** character

http://regexr.com/3apga

Comment: It's not working nginx does not seem to support ? querry.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape slashes and question mark, like this:

```
location ~ "^\/(.+)\/myservice\/f\?p=(.+)$" {
 .....
}
```

This will match first folder and p arg.

```
1 = orls
2 = 4550
```

Comment: This does not make sense, as the location is not compared against the part after `?`. "locations of all types test only a URI part of request line without arguments" Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: I don't remember this answer now, as it was long time ago, checked in online regexp and this pattern `"^\/(.+)\/myservice\/f\?p=(.+)$"` is matching two groups `orls` and `4550`, but the solution to this problem could be related to nginx, cant test and cant help right now.